# SQL Server while loop seems to nest calls

Tags: t-sql, while-loop

I have a simple SQL Server table for a many-to-many association with two numeric columns

- PFM_USER_ID
- ACCOUNT_ID

We are planning to remove the many-to-many and make a foreign key on `Account` pointing to `PFM_USER`, duplicating `Account` records (and their children) as necessary.

In planning to remove this table, I wrote the following and ran it in Squirrel, expecting the BREAK to cause the loop to end. The intent is simply to make sure that the logic I was going to develop would walk the table properly.

```
DECLARE @LastUserId INT
DECLARE @CurrentUserId INT
DECLARE @CurrentAccountId INT
DECLARE @Counter int
SET @LastUserId = 0
SET @Counter = 0

DECLARE UsersAndAccounts CURSOR LOCAL FOR 
SELECT * FROM PFM_USER_ACCOUNT ORDER BY  ACCOUNT_ID asc, PFM_USER_ID asc

OPEN UsersAndAccounts

FETCH NEXT FROM UsersAndAccounts into @CurrentUserId, @CurrentAccountId
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
     SET @Counter += 1
     IF  @Counter > 10
        BREAK 
    PRINT N'Examining Count ' + CAST(@Counter AS varchar ) + ' for USER '
       + CAST(@CurrentUserId AS varchar ) + ' and Account ' 
       + CAST(@CurrentAccountId AS varchar )
    -- A lot of logic, inserting new Accont records, copied from the existing one, goes here
    -- Many intended details omitted.
FETCH NEXT FROM UsersAndAccounts into @CurrentUserId, @CurrentAccountId
END

CLOSE UsersAndAccounts
DEALLOCATE UsersAndAccounts
```

I expected output like ( ... represent numbers I didn't capture - the values are irrelevant ):

```
Examining Count 1 for USER ... and Account ...
Examining Count 2 for USER ... and Account ...
Examining Count 3 for USER ... and Account ...
Examining Count 4 for USER ... and Account ...
Examining Count 5 for USER ... and Account ...
Examining Count 6 for USER ... and Account ...
Examining Count 7 for USER ... and Account ...
Examining Count 8 for USER 82 and Account 620
Examining Count 9 for USER 85 and Account 629
Examining Count 10 for USER 85 and Account 631
```

Instead, I get output that looks as if there are two @Counter variables and an inner loop as if it were ( cause I'm more comfortable with Java )

```
for( int count1 = 0; count1 < 10; count1++) {
    for( int count2 = count1; count2 < 10; count2) {
        System.out.println("Examining count " + count2 + " [plus other stuff]");
    }
}
```

The Squirrel console is also reporting warnings that I haven't found anything useful about. The last bit of that output that illustrates things is:

```
Warning:   Examining Count 8 for USER 82 and Account 620
SQLState:  S0001
ErrorCode: 0Warning:   Examining Count 9 for USER 85 and Account 629
SQLState:  S0001
ErrorCode: 0Warning:   Examining Count 10 for USER 85 and Account 631
SQLState:  S0001
ErrorCode: 0
Warning:   Examining Count 9 for USER 85 and Account 629
SQLState:  S0001
ErrorCode: 0Warning:   Examining Count 10 for USER 85 and Account 631
SQLState:  S0001
ErrorCode: 0
Warning:   Examining Count 10 for USER 85 and Account 631
SQLState:  S0001
ErrorCode: 0
```

I tried removed the test/BREAK inside the loop and changed the WHILE to do the test, with similar results.

Selecting top 10 and completely ignoring @Counter did the same

Please explain what I'm doing wrong, or how I'm misunderstanding what's happening here

Thanks,
George McKinney

Comment: What you are doing wrong is - RBAR processing with cursors: **ROW BY AGONIZING ROW**. Instead of describing how your debugging isn't working, tell us what your business output is supposed to look like.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following instead:

```
select 
      'Examining Count ' + ROW_NUMBER() 
    + '; USER ' + CAST(@CurrentUserId AS varchar ) 
    + ' and Account ' + CAST(@CurrentAccountId AS varchar )
from PFM_USER_ACCOUNT 
ORDER BY
    ACCOUNT_ID asc
   ,PFM_USER_ID asc
```